# (Qual Question) Example of a non-measurable function $a_{ij}:\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

The title says it all.  The question arises from a qualifying exam question in which it asks to provide an example in which we may have $A\neq B$ where
$A=\sum_{i\geq1,j\geq1}^{\infty}a_{ij}$ and $B=\sum_{j\geq1,i\geq1}^{\infty}a_{ij}$.  The iterated inner/outer sums in each expression are assumed to be absolutely convergent.

The only instance that this could fail is when $a_{ij}$ is non-measurable, by Tonelli's theorem since we have by hypothesis
$$\int_{\mathbb{Z}}\;d\#_{i}\int_{\mathbb{Z}}|a_{ij}|\;d\#_{j}<\infty,$$
i.e. the iterated integral of $|a_{ij}|$ exists and is finite and the product $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ is $\sigma$-finite with respect to counting measure (see below).

But the $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{Z}$ is just $2^{\mathbb{Z}}$, and since the product $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ is just the smallest $\sigma$-algbera which contains the sets $A\times B$ ($A\subset\mathbb{Z}$, $B\subset\mathbb{Z}$), the $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ is also just $2^{\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}}$, and this would imply all complex-valued functions on $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ are measurable, no?

So is the question incorrectly stated, or am I missing something here?  Part (b) asks for an additional assumption on $a_{ij}$ so as to guarantee the interchange of summation does not affect the sum, but it seems all "reasonable" conditions have already been imposed in part (a).

Comment: Please don't say, "The title says it all." *Always* put the question in the body. (Also, the title doesn't say it all, because you need a measure on $\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$.)

Comment: When somebody says that, they typically don't literally mean just read the title and proceed to answering the question.  It's just a summing up of the current progress/assessment of the question which is described in the body of the post, to which I mentioned the appropriate measure on $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$.  In other words, my feelings at the time of posting the question (in terms of direction in obtaining a solution) were characterized by the question's tittle.

Comment: Actually, quite a few people just leave it like that - there are loads of posts like that. Given that I didn't see in the first paragraph any instance of $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$, I had to determine whether I could answer this question with nearly no definition of the problem, so I stopped reading. If it was just me, that would be okay for you, but you risk not getting answers from lots of people who can answer your question.(When posters say, "The title says enough, and then follows with a lot of stuff, I usually think the rest of the stuff is their attempt to solve, not the question.)

Comment: Also note that, since every subset of $\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$ is measurable, any function from there to $\mathbb R$ is measurable.

Comment: Well, my apologies then.  By the way, I also mentioned this fact in paragraph #4. :P   I do understand your point though, but I think there is still a fine line between saying the title says it all and having no body in the question, between what I have (and have in most of my questions, where I have said such things in the past).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misunderstanding

> The iterated inner/outer sums in each expression are assumed to be absolutely convergent.

It does not mean that

$$\int_{\mathbb{Z}}\;d\#_{i}\int_{\mathbb{Z}}|a_{ij}|\;d\#_{j}<\infty,$$

or equivalently $\sum\limits_{i,\,j} \lvert a_{ij}\rvert < \infty$. If it did, you'd have a summable family, and all ways to sum the family would lead to the same sum.

It means that

$$\bigl(\forall i\bigr) \left(\sum_{j} \lvert a_{ij}\rvert < \infty\right),$$

and, with $b_i := \sum\limits_j a_{ij}$, you have

$$\sum_i \lvert b_i\rvert < \infty.$$

(And similarly for the other nesting.)

For an example, see [Brian's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/442400/83702)

Answer (score 4):

Let $A=[a_{ij}]$ be an infinite matrix with $1$’s on the first superdiagonal, $-1$’s on the first subdiagonal, and $0$’s elsewhere:

$$a_{ij}=\begin{cases}
1,&\text{if }i=j+1\\
-1,&\text{if }i=j-1\\
0,&\text{otherwise}\;.
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Does that double sum converge absolutely?

Comment: But it's because I misunderstood what was meant by absolute convergence of the inner and outer sums (see Daniel's answer).  I upvoted your question, but I feel compelled to accept his as the answer.  But much thanks!

Comment: @Sargera: You’re welcome!